# how to create listener for incoming messages for serial port

Tags: serial-port, at-command, sendmessage

I am creating windows form application for send/receive message using serial port. I am able to send or receive messages using AT Commnads. I want a listener for incoming messages and I used Port DataReceived Event. When a message comes, port DataReceived event raised and in port_DataReceived method I get the data on port and find if it is new message or not. if it is new message call to MessageReceived where i want to show the newly received message. 
The Problem is when i send AT+CMGL="REC UNREAD" command. It's Response write on port and port_DataReceived called again and it creates a infinite loop. How to solve this problem.

```
 public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars)
            {
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                string buffer = sp.ReadExisting();
                if (buffer.Contains("+CMTI"))
                {
                    MessageReceived(sp);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void MessageReceived(SerialPort Port)
    {
         //get the newly received message
    }
```

Comment: It is a snippet that can't possibly reproduce the problem.  It is wrong, start fixing it by using ReadLine() instead of ReadExisting.

Comment: can you provide an example of how i get newly received message.